# How to install LDAP.so on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2

Tags: php, redhat, system-administration

I've just created a brand new Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.2 server, which I am going to migrate some LAMP applications from an older RedHat 5 server.

On my old server, in the /usr/lib/php/modules directory I had the ldap.so module which I need.

In my new RedHat 6 server, in the /usr/lib64/php/modules/ directory there is no ldap.so

How do I add ldap.so ?  I'm looking for a simple solution like using yum perhaps.

Comment: "a brand new RedHat 6.2 server" I... uh... what?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you *really* meant **RHEL** 6.2, the `php-ldap` package contains the LDAP extension for PHP.

Comment: Yes you are right, Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2.  I'm going to try yum install php-ldap. Can I assume it will create an ldap.so in the extensions directory?  I'm not a sysadmin here.